# Titulo na Scrolling activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Olá, estou com um problema na scrolling activity. Eu gostaria de **esconder o titulo** quando a appbar estiver totalmente esticada e, quando retrair, o titulo voltar a ser visível. Isso é possível?

minha xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrolling"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBackground"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_scrolling" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_treinos" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olhe este tutorial

[Toolbar Animation with Android Design](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)

No final tem o código da Activity, onde mostra que tem um listener no appear, quando estiver expandido você limpa o texto

```
collapsingToolbar.setTitle("");
```

E quando reduzir mostra o texto

```
collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Texto");
```